# Get WebSocket error close sent when I navigate to other page

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am getting back error **websocket: close sent** when I try to send data from my server side to client side(dashboard page). The error happen when I navigate to home page and back to dashboard page. Everything works fine initially with the **Dashboard Page**

My dashboard page code

```
  let socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8004/wsendpoint");
        console.log("Attempting Connection...");

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Successfully Connected");
          
        };
        socket.onclose = event => {
            console.log("Socket Closed Connection: ", event);
         
        };
        socket.onerror = error => {
            console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
         
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log("message received: " + event.data);
        }
```

My Server side code (writer and reader

```
func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    // upgrade this connection to a WebSocket connection
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("upgrade error %s", err)
    }

    defer ws.Close()

    go writer(ws) 
    go reader(ws)
}
```

Writer, get data from a channel when new data come in from database

```
func writer(conn *websocket.Conn) {

    for {
        singleset := <-singleorder // get data from channel
        jsonString, err := json.Marshal(singleset ) 
        err = conn.WriteMessage(1, []byte(jsonString))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

Reader, read data from client side

```
func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        _, p, err := conn.ReadMessage() //what is message type?
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("there is errors%s", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I also got error **WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.**  and **reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8004/wsendpoint' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.**

As you can see all the code are very simple because I just start to learn websocket and follow simple tutorial. I tried to search on web but webworker seems little bit complex for me and saw about the ping pong method but I am not sure if its still valid if I navigate. Can I establish websocket on home page so the connection is not closed ? Since I only have two pages on client side.

Thanks in advance for any guidance on how to deal with these situation!

Comment: Also another note: when the function `wsEndpoint` returns, the request is stopped. So you need to keep it running as long as the client is connected. Remove the `go` keyword before `reader(ws)` to keep the connection open

Comment: @xarantolus The HTTP server abandons the request/response in the call to `upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)`.  There's no request for the server to close when `wsEndpoint` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic strategy for dealing with navigation away from the page, page close or errors is this: The client creates the websocket connection on page load.  The server expects client connections to come and go and cleans up resources when the client connection errors.

Here's why you get the error 'websocket: close sent': When the user navigates away from the page, the browser sends a [close message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1) to the server as part of the [websocket closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.4). The Gorilla package responds to the close message by sending another close message back to the client. From that point on, the server cannot send messages on the connection. The connection returns an error from write methods after the close message is sent.

Close messages are [returned as errors from the websocket read methods](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Control_Messages). To fix the problem, modify the code to handle errors in general. There's no need to handle the closing handshake specifically.

Here's the updated code. The `wsEndpoint` function creates a channel for the reader to signal the writer that the reader is done. The `defer ws.Close()` statement is removed because the reader and writer goroutines will take responsibility for closing the connection.

```
func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    // upgrade this connection to a WebSocket connection
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("upgrade error %s", err)
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})     
    go writer(ws, done) 
    go reader(ws, done)
}
```

The reader closes the connection on return. It also closes the `done` channel to signal the writer that the reader is done.

```
func reader(conn *websocket.Conn, done chan struct{}) {
    defer conn.Close()
    defer close(done)
    for {
        _, p, err := conn.ReadMessage() //what is message type?
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("there is errors%s", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The writer also closes the connection on return. When the connection is closed, read on the connection immediately returns an error causing the read goroutine to complete. The writer waits on the `done` channel.  Receive on the channel yields the zero value when the channel is closed by the reader. The writer returns on write errors instead of looping forever as in the question.

```
func writer(conn *websocket.Conn, done chan struct{}) {
    defer conn.Close()
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            // the reader is done, so return
            return
        case singleset := <-singleorder: // get data from channel
            jsonString, err := json.Marshal(singleset ) 
            err = conn.WriteMessage(1, []byte(jsonString))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An application should expect the connection to be closed for any number of reasons including the user navigating away from the page.

It's likely that the code that sends to channel `singleorder` needs to know that the connection was closed, but we cannot see that code here. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks @Cerise Limón, I think I get what you mean. If the connection is closed, can I handle it using Ping Pong method to reconnect? Any good suggestion to handle this navigating away situation in websocket? 
PS: I am still reading [link](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples) given by comment above, but need time to digest especially how to fit into my situation.

Comment: @Perfectisshit  (1) the server handles errors as described in this answer (2) the client reconnects on page load as shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reconnect on page load hints and the server handle errors method, I will try to puzzle it out.

Comment: @Perfectisshit The basic strategy for dealing with navigation away from the page, page close or errors is this: The client creates the websocket connection on page load.  You do this already. The server expects client connections to come and go and cleans up resources when the client connection errors.  My answer shows you how to cleanup resources in your application.  Ping/Pong improves the detection of errored clients, it does not help  with reconnect.

Comment: I refer to your answer and online documentation now it able to work, thanks a lot!  Is it I miss out to close the writer connection initially causing it keep on writing to the broken connection?

Comment: @Perfectisshit  The `writer` in the question has two problems (1) It ignores error except for printing the error.  The function should break out of the loop on error. (2) The function does not cleanup resources on return.

Comment: Hi @CharlieTumahai, I can see that there's no error check when closing the connection in both `reader()` and `writer()` (`defer conn.Close()`). I was wondering how to handle this in a clean way by using a `isClosed()` method or something else. Thank you so much

Comment: @Big_Boulard It is safe to call Close multiple times.  I did not check the error returned from Close there is nothing the application can do when Close fails.